# How to lift Signal rate limit using PUSH_CHALLENGE only?

Tags: rate-limiting

I use [signal-cli](https://github.com/AsamK/signal-cli) desktop client to communicate with **Signal** messenger.
Recently, I started to get rate limit error that didn't have **RECAPTCHA** option, but **PUSH_CHALLENGE** only. It looks like:

```
+XXXXXXXXCXXX: CAPTCHA proof required for sending to "+XXXXXXXXXXXX", available options "PUSH_CHALLENGE" with challenge token "22251d74-6ae4-46fb-95cb-4683fbe0f095", or wait "86400" seconds.
```

Is there a way how to solve it from **signal-cli** using **PUSH_CHALLENGE** only?